# Is there any complete tutorial for setting up a full QEMU-KVM from hypervisor to host through command line ?

Tags: libvirt, qemu, virsh

I've found parts about how to use `virt-install` from scratch or almost like http://virt-tools.org/learning/install-with-command-line/

However I'm stuck at connecting to the VM through `virsh` once the first part is done. Most tutorial use graphical client, I would like to be able to do it on a remote server which has no UI layer. Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is for you to install [virt-manager](http://virt-manager.org/) on your local machine. You can use it to connect to libvirt on the remote machine and then open the remote VMs' graphical consoles.

Comment: virt-manager can tunnel libvirt over SSH, so all you really need is to set up authorized SSH keys and go.

Comment: That sounds like a neat solution. I'll try it and provide you with some feedback.